# How to create a range of dates in R

Tags: r, date

From two integers `(1, 5)` one can create a range in the following way

```
1:5
```

> [1] 1 2 3 4 5

How can you make a range of dates if you are give two dates `("2014-09-04 JST", "2014-09-11 JST")`

The output must be

> [1] ("2014-09-04 JST", "2014-09-05 JST", "2014-09-06 JST", "2014-09-07 JST", "2014-09-08 JST")

Comment: Well, if you have a timezone, then they are not Dates but rather datetimes. There are `seq`-methods for either class.

Comment: Can you answer this question for date + timezone?

Comment: @sjdh See comment to jalapic answer.

Comment: @sjdh - would be great if you could give an answer a tick to close the question. thanks.

Comment: Good solutions here, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450384/create-a-vector-of-all-days-between-two-dates

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Does this help?

```
seq(as.Date("2014/09/04"), by = "day", length.out = 5)
# [1] "2014-09-04" "2014-09-05" "2014-09-06" "2014-09-07" "2014-09-08"
```

**edit: adding in something about timezones**

this works for my current timezone

```
seq(c(ISOdate(2014,4,9)), by = "DSTday", length.out = 5) 
#[1] "2014-04-09 08:00:00 EDT" "2014-04-10 08:00:00 EDT" "2014-04-11 08:00:00 EDT" "2014-04-12 08:00:00 EDT"
#[5] "2014-04-13 08:00:00 EDT"
```

**edit2:**

```
OlsonNames()  # I used this to find out what to write for the JST tz - it's "Japan"

x <- as.POSIXct("2014-09-04 23:59:59", tz="Japan")
format(seq(x, by="day", length.out=5), "%Y-%m-%d %Z")

# [1] "2014-09-04 JST" "2014-09-05 JST" "2014-09-06 JST" "2014-09-07 JST" "2014-09-08 JST"
```

Comment: How about `format( seq(c(ISOdate(2014,4,9)), by = "DSTday", length.out = 5), "%Y-%m-%d %Z")`

Comment: If I give you these two dates ("2014-09-04 JST", "2014-09-11 JST") can you construct a sequence too? With result in JST? (In case you are curious, JST stands for Japanese Standard Time)

Comment: Not sure why this was accepted. It doesn't answer the question. "*How can you make a range of dates if you are give (sic) two dates?*"

Answer (score 24):

To get a sequence of dates ( days, weeks,.. ) using only start and end dates you can use:

```
seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2014/1/10"), "days”)

[1] "2014-01-01" "2014-01-02" "2014-01-03" "2014-01-04" "2014-01-05" "2014-01-06" "2014-01-07"
[8] "2014-01-08" "2014-01-09" "2014-01-10”
```

Comment: seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2014/1/10"),by="day")

Comment: Also, the original had smart quotes doing their evil business.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer, admittedly worse than @jalapic's, that doesn't use seq and instead uses a for loop:

```
date1 <- "2014-09-04"
date2 <- "2014-09-11"
dif <- as.numeric(abs(as.Date(date1) - as.Date(date2)))
dates <- vector()
for (i in 1:dif) {
  date <- (as.Date(date1) + i)
  dates <- append(dates, date)
}
# [1] "2014-09-05" "2014-09-06" "2014-09-07" "2014-09-08" "2014-09-09" "2014-09-10" "2014-09-11
```

Comment: There's no reason to use a loop for this.

Answer (score 0):

here's a shot though the timezone JST isn't recognized by my system

```
d1<-ISOdate(year=2014,month=9,day=4,tz="GMT")
seq(from=d1,by="day",length.out=5)
[1] "2014-09-04 12:00:00 GMT" "2014-09-05 12:00:00 GMT" "2014-09-06 12:00:00 GMT" "2014-09-07 12:00:00 GMT" "2014-09-08 12:00:00 GMT"
```

Answer (score 0):

While using `seq(date1, date2, "days")` is by far the better option in nearly all cases, I'd just like to add, that the following works too, if you need a range of dates that are n_number of days from a date:

```r
1:10 + as.Date("2020-01-01")

# [1] "2020-01-02" "2020-01-03" "2020-01-04" "2020-01-05"
# [5] "2020-01-06" "2020-01-07" "2020-01-08" "2020-01-09"
# [9] "2020-01-10" "2020-01-11"
```