# How to format a Date as "YYYY-Mon" with Lubridate?

Tags: r, date, format, lubridate

I would like to create a vector of dates between two specified moments in time with step 1 month, as described in this thread ([Create a Vector of All Days Between Two Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14450384/4518857)), to be then converted into factors for data visualization.

However, I'd like to have the dates in the YYYY-Mon, ie. 2010-Feb, format. But so far I managed only to have the dates in the standard format 2010-02-01, using a code like this:

```
require(lubridate)
first <- ymd_hms("2010-02-07 15:00:00 UTC")
start <- ymd(floor_date(first, unit="month"))

last <- ymd_hms("2017-10-29 20:00:00 UTC")
end <- ymd(ceiling_date(last, unit="month"))

> start
[1] "2010-02-01"

> end
[1] "2017-11-01"
```

How can I change the format to YYYY-Mon?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `format()`:

```
start %>% format('%Y-%b')
```

To create the vector, use `seq()`:

```
seq(start, end, by = 'month') %>% format('%Y-%b')
```

Obs: Use capital 'B' for full month name: `'%Y-%B'`.

Comment: That works, thanks.
Now, how to keep the '%Y-%b' format in the by-month sequence from start t oend date?

Comment: Great! You can use `seq()`: `seq(start, end, by = 'month') %>% format('%Y-%b')`.

Comment: Yes, I got there on my own too. But I appreciate your assistance anyway.

Comment: Note that format() is a base R function and will change the vector from date-time to character.